# Why is VS Code showing "windll Windows only: Creates ()" intellisense suggestions?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

While writing Python code on VS Code, it is showing suggestions like:

> windll Windows only: Creates ()

I have tried to see if this was coming from snippet extension I might have installed but I don't think I have any... can anyone shine a light on why I am getting his code completion nonsense?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue, every time `:`, `.`, `def`, or `if` is typed, there's annoying suggestions that don't make sense. I found out it's the [Python Extended](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tushortz.python-extended-snippets#:%7E:text=Python%20Extended-,Python%20Extended%20is%20a%20vscode%20snippet%20that%20makes%20it%20easy,options%20along%20with%20all%20arguments.) extension that's responsible for this. It [seems to be reported on it's GitHub issues page](https://github.com/tushortz/vscode-Python-Extended/issues), but for now I would disable the extension as it doesn't seem to be working at all for me. I recommend [PyLance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

**It's the extension problem.
You have installed the extension named: [Python Extended](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tushortz.python-extended-snippets)  inside your vs code and you will need to uninstall it.
It works well on my editor after uninstalling this extension.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).