# Why does my ':' show "Windows only Oledll" in the intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is an example when trying to write a Python function with the autocomplete showing:

[image: vscode example]

What happens after I hit space:

[image: what happens after i hit space]

So the problem is that each time I try to write a code with a ":", for some reason, the aforementioned autocomplete happens right after I hit space. It's frustrating since each time I write a code, this will pop up even with the `if` conditions or any statement which has ":" in it.

I am on a Mac OS Big Sur, I really love VS Code, but I can't seem to figure out the cause of this problem.

Comment: If there is a downvote please tell me whats wrong with the way i asked the question.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this as well, so thank you for asking. Going to keep digging to see why this is happening @sam tershek

Comment: hey @MalcolmJones this is the thread that helped me out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649240/why-is-vs-code-showing-windll-windows-only-creates-intellisense-suggestion,

Uhm i found it was to do with the python Extended extension, so I disabled it temporarily until they sort out the issue. But you can find the full explanation in the thread.

Comment: you my friend just made my day, thank you so much!!